# How to find the month to date cost of a SoftLayer VSI?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to construct a REST query to get the month to date cost of my hourly instance at Softlayer. I need to do some comparisons between the VSI and one of my instances at AWS.

I am a little unsure if I should be calling on Softlayer_account or Billing_Item?

Answer (score 2):

This request can help you to get the Date, cost for Virtual Guest’ invoices:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/[vsi_id]/getBillingItem?objectMask=mask[hoursUsed,hourlyRecurringFee,currentHourlyCharge,invoiceItems[recurringFee,hourlyRecurringFee,createDate]]
```

**Where:**

```
createDate: The date the invoice item was created.
recurringFee: The recurring fee of the invoice item represented by a floating point decimal in US Dollars ($USD)
```

To get more information about the meaning of these values, please see:

> http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Billing_Invoice_Item

Other references:

```
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Billing_Item
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Billing_Item/getInvoiceItems
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getBillingItem
```